# How to take ScreenShot in selenium for chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot in google chrome. So can anyone provide me the code for taking a screenshot?

Comment: I am using selenium java. I searched for an answer but didn't saw a favorable one. so some simple code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void TakeScreenshot() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//Screenshots//Screenshot_taken_on_" + LocalDateTime.now().toString().subSequence(0, 19).toString().replace(":", ".") + ".png"));  
}
```

The above code will take a screenshot and copy it to the screenshots folder in project directory with a timestamp in the filename. Where ever you want to take a screenshot just call this method that's it.

EX: Screenshot_taken_on_2022-03-08T14.47.06.png

```
   @Test(priority=1, enabled=true)
    public void Click_test() throws InterruptedException, IOException 
{
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://yoururl");

     TakeScreenshot(); //This method will take screenshot of opened/active chrome window

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'icon-more')]")).click();

     TakeScreenshot(); //This method will take screenshot of opened/active chrome window
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Capture and save the screenshot:

```
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Step 2: Store it in our local drive:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("filename_with_path"));
```

For Example:

```
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("D:\\Automation\\error.png"));
```

Note: For saving the screenshot you want a jar file of org.apache.commons.io. Download from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4)

Kindly import the jar file in your project.

Comment: Can you share with me your code. Also tell me if any error throw in a console.

Comment: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Enter the URL
driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");

//I Agree PopUp
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'I Agree')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
Files.copy(screenshotFile, new File("E:\\selenium\\err.png"));

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\selenium\err.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:292)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSink.openStream(Files.java:192)
at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSink.openStream(Files.java:180)
at com.google.common.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java
at com.google.common.io.Files.copy
at MariaTash.Screenshot.main

Comment: The exception says your path is not valid. kindly verify that 'E:\selenium' folder exists on your machine.